# Spark Structured Streaming - How to ignore checkpoint?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm reading messages from Kafka stream using microbatching (`readStream`), processing them and writing results to another Kafka topic via `writeStream`. The job (streaming query) is designed to run "forever", processing microbatches of size 10 seconds (of processing time). The `checkpointDirectory` option is set, since Spark requires checkpointing.

However, when I try to submit another query with the same source stream (same topic etc.) but possibly different processing algorithm), Spark finishes the previous running query and creates a new one *with the same ID* (so it starts from the very same offset on which the previous job "finished").

How to tell Spark that the second job is different from the first one, so there is no need to restore from checkpoint (i.e. intended behaviour is to create a completely new streaming query not connected to previous one, and keep the previous one running)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve independence of the two streaming queries by setting the `checkpointLocation` option in their respective writeStream call. You should *not* set the checkpoint location centrally in the SparkSession.

That way, they can run independently and will not interfere from each other.